# Log4J Web Based Log Viewer

Tags: web-apps, java, logs

My Java application is logging to a file and I currently read it with a desktop application that splits it out into columns something like below:

```
| Timestamp           | Level  | Category                          | Message   |
| ------------------- |:------:|:---------------------------------:| -------------------------------------------:|
| 2019-02-28 12:16:36 | INFO   | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler  |
| 2019-02-28 12:16:40 | ERROR  | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Failed to find path......                   |
| 2019-02-28 12:16:45 | DEBUG  | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Loading from jar                            |
```

A bit similar to Apache Chainsaw really:
[image]

The columns can be sorted and filtered.

I now need to move to a web based solution.

[Elastic with logstash and kibana](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) has been suggested but it looks overly complicated and does a lot more than just displaying the logs.

Also, [Kibana doesn't seem to be able to highlight rows](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/23613) based on log level in the same way as the screenshot above.

I don't want to pay for [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com).

Is there an alternative that balances being up to date and not too complicated?

Comment: What is the format of your logs? Just simple text files? Are you willing to add an appender to append logs to another destination such as a database?

Comment: Just normal text based log file. DB Appender is fine, I don't want to custom write everything though